# Change 'src' value by css for input tag with type="image"

Tags: html, css, markup

Is it possible to change the value of src attribute of `<input type='image' alt="Text will be shown if pics are disabled" src='somepic.png'../>` by css?

The problem is: 
I want to specify which pic will be shown as submit button just using css (so the design team will change only css files!). 
If I use the alternative way like `<input type="submit" class="cssclass" value=" " alt="Text will be shown if pics are disabled"/>` and specify the background of this element in css - it doesn't work well if pics are disabled.  - No any alternative text is shown instead of pic. However the first way solves this situation...

Please advice something

Thanks.

Comment: I really really really really _really_ _REALLY_ hope it's not possible with CSS/

Comment: @Zirak well I'll try tomorrow the possibility... to place transparent '1*1.gif' to src attribute, and also make a background real image by css. I really REALLY REALLY hope it should work - otherwise I will have to use the JS solution

Answer (score 2):

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/66JXn/

Some notes about this solution:

1. Use `<button></button>`, 'cause it can include other blocks.
2. You'll need a bit of extra code to make all these work in Fx and IE:

   - For Fx you need an extra wrapper inside (there are positioning bug) and some extra -moz- properties reset.
   - For IE you must shrink the original button, 'cause there are some extra padding that is hard to remove.
3. You place the text and another element inside, that would overlay the text. So when the images would absent, the text would be accessible.

That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

Attribute selectors might work, but they aren't very flexible. Try this one:

```
img[src=""] {
  background-image: url('none.png');
  height: 100px; /* Height of BG image */
  width: 100px; /* Width of BG image */
}
```

It doesn't change the image's `src=` attribute, but it performs the same function.

---

Here's my idea.

You can use JavaScript to *read* the stylesheets of `<img>` tags, and modify them accordingly.

I'm talking about a class whitelist, like `big, small, center` and all other classes applied to the images are interpreted via JavaScript. The design team could use CSS, but it would not render in the expected manor, like this (Python + JavaScript):

```
for every <img> tag:
  if tag.classes contains class not in whitelist:
    for every class not in whitelist:
      this.src = newClass.backgroundImage;
      this.removeClass(newClass)
```

It reads the CSS for the `background-image` property, but it just steals the URL of the image and sets the `src=` attribute using that URL. Then, the JavaScript would delete that class, causing it not to render.

Comment: didn't understand how it can help in my situation :( I already have excellent selector - class="cssclass"... So the point is not to use background-image, because in this case if images are disabled browser doesnt show the alt text too (in case of input type=submit). Alt text shows only if src attribute is filled and its input type=image.

Comment: Can your phrase your question a bit more clearly? I'm not understanding it.

Comment: 1. If I use the <input type='image' alt="Text will be shown if pics are disabled" src='somepic.png'.. class="cssclass"/>. Good: alt text shown if pics are disabled. Bad: design team cannot specify another pic for this cssclass, cause it is already specified by src attribute. 2. If I use <input type="submit" class="cssclass" value=" " alt="Text will be shown if pics are disabled"/> and .cssclass {background-image: url('somepic.png');}. Good: Designers can change this pic to any they want in css. Bad: alt text doesnot show on the page if pics are disabled. Hope now it's understandable:)

Comment: Gotcha. You can't change that with CSS, but you can do this with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

No, and this is bad practice. CSS is for static content only.

What you *should* do, is define a template file with variables in it such as:

template.js

```
my_backgroundImage = "url('somepic.png')";
```

then your file would load

```
x = document.createElement('image');
x.src = my_backgroundImage
```

Comment: our css are static of course, but design team has access to it in svn. And they have no access to any js files, so your solution does not look very appropriate...

Comment: @javagirl Your file access restrictions are actually the inappropriate part of this conversation. A design team should not have access to js without the css, or css without the js. They are complimentary languages more then explicit ones.

Sometimes I wonder how companies survive with all anti-productive practices they employ for 'safety' and 'security' reasons.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a problem for which JS is the solution, but ignoring that:)

One option is to wrap the button and an extra `div` (lets call it `div.overlay`) in a parent container.

Set the container to to `position:relative`.

Set the button to only display text, as usual. Set the `div.overlay` to `position:absolute`, `width` and `height` to `100%`, and `left` and `top` to `0`, and a `z-index` higher than the button. Set the image you want to display as the `background-image` of `div.overlay`.

With images enabled, the user sees the image, and the image can be changed using only CSS.

With images, or CSS disabled, the user only sees the plaintext submit button.

You might have to do some trickery to get clicking `div.overlay` to submit the form, perhaps just make `div.overlay` a duplicate submit button. Also, who knows what Googlebot makes of overlay techniques like these.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but the only pure CSS solution that immediately jumps to mind is a kind of image replacement with relatively poor support.  That's using :after.  It's kind of a poor practice due to the misuse of :after, and the support is pretty iffy, and I think it'd be iffier for an input element, based on the last time I tried to use :after on an input...

```
.cssclass,
.cssclass:after{
display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.cssclass{ position:relative; }
.cssclass:after{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
    content:url("button.jpg");
}
```

See http://www.rachaelmoore.name/best-practices/css-image-replacement-ii/ for more.

Or setting the default src to a shim and always using CSS to set the desired button as a background image.  Which I just noticed you've already thought of.  I imagine that should work just fine.

Comment: img, input, select, textarea -- none reliably have pseudoelements (which is mostly spec)

Answer (score 1):

Ok...  So I hate it when I ask a specific question and, instead of answering it, they give me some crappy work-around instead of answering the original question that I asked...  But for some reason, I've decided that I'm going to do it to you.

If I understand the problem correctly, you just want to have a form button with a background image and if the background image *doesn't* load, you want some sort of alt text displayed to the user with the caption of the button?  If that's not right, stop reading and "down arrow" me.

In apps that I've made, I've always just styled the input with a background image, but left it up to the HTML control to insert text...  It's good for three reasons...  buttons can be styled, developers can change the value of the text on the button without having to bother me to make a new image, and if the background image doesn't load, the button is still readable.

So my html was like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSearch" class="searchButton" value="Search">
```

then my class may read something like:

```
.searchButton {
 backgorund-image: url('searchButtonImage.png');
 font-family: sans serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #808080;
 padding-left: 50px 0px 0px 0px; // Assuming a magnifying glass icon or whatevs is on the left and is 20-ish pixels
 width: 100px; // you can put this as in-line style if you make a more generic class
}
```

If you want to make the BG more generic, move the width of the button to make it in-line on the button, so the devs can change the width with the text value and make your generic bg image like 200px wide.

Depending on the browser, the text might not be as nice and ani-aliased as in others, but IMO, it's a small price to pay.

(Disclaimer: Please forgive me if you copy and paste this and it doen't work.  I just hand-wrote it without testing it.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it with javascript?

I have an image on my page that, when clicked, will show another button, and also change the src attribute of the first.

Here is what I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function apps()
 {
 var element = document.getElementById("app_frame");
 if (element.width != "0%")
 {
    parent.document.getElementById("frame").setAttribute("width","100%");
    parent.document.getElementById("app_frame").setAttribute("width","0%");
    parent.document.getElementById("appbutton").setAttribute("src","site/main/images/apps/show.gif");
    parent.document.getElementById("wthrbutton").style.visibility="hidden";
 }
 else
 {
    parent.document.getElementById("frame").setAttribute("width","65%");
    parent.document.getElementById("app_frame").setAttribute("width","35%");
    parent.document.getElementById("appbutton").setAttribute("src","site/main/images/apps/hide.gif");
    parent.document.getElementById("wthrbutton").style.visibility="visible";
 }
 }
 </script>
```

What that says, is: set the "app_frame" as variable "element",
then check variable "element" for its width.
if its width is not 0, then it gets the element "frame",
by using getElementById, and then sets the attribute "width" to 100%

you can see slightly lower down that you use the same method, but use the SRC attribute rather than width, and set it to whatever you want, in my case, site/main/images/apps/show.gif

hope that helps